# Opposite of page find in capybara

Tags: capybara

If know that capybara has a way to find something on a page with

```
page.find
```

Is there an opposite to this for page does not find?

Comment: What are you trying to find exactly?

Comment: so something like 'page does not find'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
page.has_css?(your selector)
```

Will return if the page has it visible

```
page.has_content?(your content)
```

Will return if the text is visible.